# Sites not loading after changing WAMP port

Tags: php

I changed apache port to 8080 and called wordpress and Codeigniter sites. Although simple php projects are able to be called, these wordpress and codeigniter projects are not loading. Not showing errors, but showing nothing.

http://postimg.org/image/vvnrxfqmn/

Comment: You can try to start and stop all web  service.

Comment: I use wamp and I restarted services after changing ports.But not working as well.